# Swiftui The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: api, search, swiftui, urlsession, jsondecoder

I am getting the above error when i run my code, using an api. I double checked copying the json file and running it locally it worked correctly, i cant seem to get where the error is coming from,

Countries.swift

```
struct APIResult: Codable {
    var data: APICountryData
}

struct APICountryData: Codable {
    var count: Int
    var results: [Countries]
}

struct Countries: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var abrname: String
    var flag_url: URL
    var info: String
}
```

CountriesViewModel.swift

```
class CountriesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var searchQuery = ""
    
    var searchCancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
    
    //Fetched Data....
    @Published var fetchCountries: [Countries]? = nil
        
    @Published var offset: Int = 0
    
    init() {
        
        searchCancellable = $searchQuery
            .removeDuplicates()
            .debounce(for: 0.6, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: { str in
                if str == ""{
                    // reset Data...
                    self.fetchCountries = nil
                } else {
                    //search Data...
                    self.searchCountry()
                }
            })
    }
    
    
    
    func searchCountry() {
        
        let url = "my api url"
        
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, _, err) in
            
            if let error = err{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            guard let APIData = data else {
                print("No Data found")
                return
            }
            
            do {
                
                // Decoding API Data....
                let countrys = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResult.self, from: APIData)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    if self.fetchCountries == nil {
                        self.fetchCountries = countrys.data.results
                    }
                }
            }
            catch{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
        }
        .resume()
    }
    
}
```

When i test it on the simulator it runs, but when i search it brings up this error "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."

Sample of my json data

```
[
    {
        "id" : "0",
        "name" : "Afghanistan",
        "abrname" : "AFG",
        "flag_url" : "Image URL",
        "info" : "Afghanistan (/Ã¦fËˆÉ¡Ã¦nÉªstÃ¦n, Ã¦fËˆÉ¡É‘ËnÉªstÉ‘Ën/ (About this soundlisten);[23] Pashto/Dari: Ø§ÙØºØ§Ù†Ø³ØªØ§Ù† AfÄ¡ÄnestÄn, Pashto pronunciation: [afÉ£É‘nÉªstÉ‘n], Dari pronunciation: [afÉ£É’ËnÉªstÉ’Ën]), officially the Islamic Emirate of Afghanistan, is a landlocked country at the crossroads of Central and South Asia. It is bordered by Pakistan to the east and south, Iran to the west, Turkmenistan and Uzbekistan to the north, and Tajikistan and China to the northeast. Occupying 652,864 square kilometres (252,072 sq mi), the country is predominately mountainous with plains in the north and the southwest that are separated by the Hindu Kush mountains. Its population as of 2020 is 31.4 million, composed mostly of ethnic Pashtuns, Tajiks, Hazaras, and Uzbeks. Kabul serves as its capital and largest city."
    },
    {
        "id" : "1",
        "name" : "Andorra",
        "abrname" : "AND",
        "flag_url" : "Image URL",
        "info" : "Andorra[g], officially the Principality of Andorra,[1][h] is a sovereign landlocked microstate on the Iberian Peninsula, in the eastern Pyrenees, bordered by France to the north and Spain to the south. Believed to have been created by Charlemagne, Andorra was ruled by the count of Urgell until 988, when it was transferred to the Roman Catholic Diocese of Urgell. The present principality was formed by a charter in 1278. It is headed by two co-princes: the Bishop of Urgell in Catalonia, Spain and the President of France. Its capital and also its largest city is Andorra la Vella. "
    }
]
```

Comment: Replace `print(error.localizedDescription)` with `print(error)` to get the real error.

Comment: Also, don't throw away the server response. You need to be able to know what is going on there. And, as a habit, you should throw a guard on the URL and not force unwrap it.

Comment: After replacing print(error.localizedDescription) with print(error)    2021-10-16 05:29:46.093362+0800 Country Search[65184:1005713] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: I mean the line in the `catch` scope. The first error doesn’t occur.

Comment: Got it  2021-10-16 05:38:06.838399+0800 Country Search[65243:1010598] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: This says that your root object is an array. You should decode `[APIResult].self`

Comment: @EMPIRE post a sample of your JSON data

Comment: @vadian in decoding  i get this error in DispatchQueue.main.async Value of type '[APIResult]' has no member 'data'

Comment: @jnpdx i'll update my question with a sample of the json data

Comment: `let countries = try JSONDecoder().decode([Countries].self, from: APIData)` `self.fetchCountries = countries`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is wrong.

Replace

```
let countrys = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResult.self, from: APIData)
            
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
    if self.fetchCountries == nil {
        self.fetchCountries = countrys.data.results
    }
}
```

With

```
let countries = try JSONDecoder().decode([Countries].self, from: APIData)
            
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.fetchCountries = countries
}
```

the other two structs make no sense.

And declare `fetchCountries` as non-optional empty array and name the struct in singular form `Country`.

Comment: Finally progress, using your answer it worked but now all the countries are showing up when i search, the other 2 structs ( APICountryData and APIResult ) are to help filter out my search results. Thanks for your time though.